# Insert cell in tableview in swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, uitableview

I'm currently doing an app in swift and doing a menubar that scrolls from the right of the screen and display a list of possibilities.

I created the UITableView on my storyboard as a view that I sticked over the Navigation Controller.

I want now to add cells to this tableview to create a navigation bar, but I don't know how do it since there's no controller managing the item ***menuView***.
Here is my ViewControllerClass:

```
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var menuView: UITableView!

var menuShowing = false
@IBOutlet weak var leadingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    menuView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    menuView.layer.shadowRadius = 6

}

@IBAction func openMenu(_ sender: Any) {
    if (menuShowing)
    {
        leadingConstraint.constant = -200
        UIView.animate(withDuration:  0.3, animations: {self.view.layoutIfNeeded()})
    } else {
        leadingConstraint.constant = 0
        UIView.animate(withDuration:  0.3, animations: {self.view.layoutIfNeeded()})
    }
    menuShowing  = !menuShowing
}
}
```

My questions are :
Is my menuView object well done or should I reconsider my previous work?

Can I add a cell in the menuView object simply with a simple function like:
    MenuView.addRow( *** something ***)?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the UITableViewDataSource and if you want to UITableViewDelegate to ViewController to make the tableView be controlled by ViewController.

```
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

 @IBOutlet weak var menuView: UITableView!

var menuShowing = false
@IBOutlet weak var leadingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()


menuView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
menuView.layer.shadowRadius = 6
menuView.dataSource = self
menuView.delegate = self

 }

// Handle TableView like you normally do:

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    return UITableViewCell()
}

 @IBAction func openMenu(_ sender: Any) {
if (menuShowing)
{
    leadingConstraint.constant = -200
    UIView.animate(withDuration:  0.3, animations: {self.view.layoutIfNeeded()})
} else {
    leadingConstraint.constant = 0
    UIView.animate(withDuration:  0.3, animations: {self.view.layoutIfNeeded()})
}
menuShowing  = !menuShowing
 }
   }
```